# Google API is returning a 401 or 404

Tags: google-api

I am making this GET request:

[https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%7BCALENDAR) ID}/events&key={API KEY}

Where CALENDAR ID is my calendar id and API KEY is my API key.
Both are found within my Google Cloud console.

I am making this request in Postman as well as from Google's own [sample website](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/insert?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22summary%22%3A%22%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22123434%22%7D%7D).

If I request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR ID}/events&key={API KEY}
```

This returns me a 404.

However, requesting (without "/events"):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR ID}&key={API KEY}
```

Will return me a 401.

The 404 message is clear - this API does not support API keys. For this, my understanding is that API keys CAN be used for the Calendar API if i make the calendar public (which it is).

Am I missing something here, or does the Calendar API absolutely require OAuth2 access token. What I am looking for is a solution to request/create events in my calendar from the server side (no user interaction).

Comment: is your API key enabled for the Calendar API?

Comment: My API restrictions is set to "Dont restrict key"

Comment: And also, Google Calendar API (under My project's product details) says it is "API Enabled"

Comment: I am using SO's new "Ask with AI" lab feature. It provided a clear answer. basically i need to use a service account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed your URL uses the "&" without having a "?" before (thus the API-Key isn't given as an GET-Parameter). With this it should work:

> [https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CALENDAR](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%7BCALENDAR) ID}/events?key={API KEY}

For more Information maybe look at the API-Reference: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference#Events

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Im afraid i just made a typo. Note that im using Postman, so the query parameters are generated automatically as im providing the query parameters thru the GUI.